# Optimize the function to extract data from long string to and Object keys & values

Tags: javascript, node.js, algorithm, big-o

I have a string that gets from the text file. In each line, it looks like this.

`1=abc|2=TsMarketDataCache|3=1|4=141061|6=2023-02-27T05:04:50.472|36=F|7=1584A`

Pattern: *key1=value1|key2=value2|key3=value3|key4=value4...|keyN=valueN*

The goal is to split the string by '|' and get the key=value to the Object like this:

```
{
 '1': 'abc',
 '2': 'TsMarketDataCache',
 '3': '1',
 '4': '141061',
 ....
}
```

So I created a function in many ways that produce the same result.
**My Solution:**

```
// First approach (execution time around 1-2 seconds)
const translate = (msg) => {
  const keyValues = msg.split("|");
  const result = keyValues.reduce((acc, keyValue, index) => {
     const [key, value] = keyValue.split("=");
     acc[key] = value;
     return acc;
  }, {});

  return result;
};

// Second approach (execution time around 5-6 seconds)
const translate = (msg) => {
  let index;
  let result = {};
  let acc = "";
  const len = msg.length;

  for (index = 0; index < len; index++) {
    if (msg[index] != "|") {
      acc += msg[index];
    } else {
      const [key, value] = acc.split("=");
      result[key] = value;
      
      acc = "";
    }
  }
  const [key, value] = acc.split("=");
  result[key] = value;

  return result;
};
```

In the real case, the message data will be get from a text file that is around 3 million lines (very big).
So I just implement a code to test the execution time from the function above.
just loop 100000 times

```
// Just an example

let message = `1=Instrument%2@id%1'CHMOBI28C2303A_SYMB'%3|2=TsMarketDataCache|3=1|4=141061|6=2023-02-27T05:04:50.472|36=F|7=1584A|8=CHMOBI28C2303A_SYMB|9=SET_STOCK_DERIVATIVE_WARRANT_FOREIGN_UNDERLYING|10=T|11=T|12=0|13=CHMOBI28C2303A|14=SYMB|15=THB|16=CHMOBI28C2303A|17=SET|18=STOCK|19=DERIVATIVE_WARRANT_FOREIGN_UNDERLYING|20=700000|22=88138|23=1|24=100000000|25=F|27=372|28=1|31=2022-10-31|38=N/A|501=V|502=F|503=14000000|504=10000|531=F|506=F|507=F|508=F|509=3|510=3|525=700000|518=2023-02-24|522=T|51=F`;

console.time();
for (let i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
  translate(message);
}
console.timeEnd();
```

the execution time of the **first** approach: **1-2 seconds**

the execution time of the **second** approach: **5-6 seconds**

from my understand

the first approach:

*O(n) + O(m) + O(s)
// split by '|'  +  reduce  + split by '='*

the second one:

*O(n) + O(s)
// for loop through string  +  split by '='*

Why the first approach is faster than the second one ?

Could someone explain?

Or if you find a better optimize solution it'd be great.

Comment: its O(n) if u assume split is O(1). i think split is O(string length). reduce is also O(n)

Comment: Yes, the first approach it's like O(n) + O(m) + O(s) // split + reduce + split in reduce
and the second approach it's just loop through string O(n) + O(s) // for loop + split by =

But the first approach it's a lot faster than the second one.

Comment: `acc += msg[index];` is most likely the culprit that makes the second implementation very inefficient.

Comment: What you say `O(n)`, what does `n` refer to?

Comment: n refer to the length of msg string

Comment: "*It seems like the seconds approach uses Big O(n).*" - no, a single benchmark says nothing about time complexity. And contrasted to what? "*I feel like it should be faster than the first one.*" - why do you feel like that?

Comment: Btw, why are you doing `keyName = index + "_" + key`? That doesn't match your desired output format.

Comment: If `n` is the length of the string, the first approach is `O(n)` whereas the second approach is somewhere between `O(n)` and `O(n²)`, depending a) on how efficient the engine implements string-character concatenation and b) on how many key-value pairs there are in the input

Comment: Oh, I forgot to remove the keyName = index + "_" + key.
The real data may have duplicate key.

Comment: Maybe if you use `Object.fromEntries` it'll be faster? `const result = Object.fromEntries(keyValues.map((kv) => kv.split("=")));`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`msg.split("|")` is faster than simply iterating the string with a JS for loop (At least in this specific case). Calling a predefined function like `split` delegates the logic to the browser engine (like V8 in chrome). That'll take advantage of the C code in the engine which has been optimized for decades.

I don't know exactly what black magic happens in there, but it's fast:

```js
let msg = `1=Instrument%2@id%1'CHMOBI28C2303A_SYMB'%3|2=TsMarketDataCache|3=1|4=141061|6=2023-02-27T05:04:50.472|36=F|7=1584A|8=CHMOBI28C2303A_SYMB|9=SET_STOCK_DERIVATIVE_WARRANT_FOREIGN_UNDERLYING|10=T|11=T|12=0|13=CHMOBI28C2303A|14=SYMB|15=THB|16=CHMOBI28C2303A|17=SET|18=STOCK|19=DERIVATIVE_WARRANT_FOREIGN_UNDERLYING|20=700000|22=88138|23=1|24=100000000|25=F|27=372|28=1|31=2022-10-31|38=N/A|501=V|502=F|503=14000000|504=10000|531=F|506=F|507=F|508=F|509=3|510=3|525=700000|518=2023-02-24|522=T|51=F`;

function splitTest() {
  console.time('split');
  for (let i=0; i<1e6; i++) msg.split("|");
  console.timeEnd('split');
}

function iterateTest() {
  console.time('iterate');
  for (let i=0; i<1e6; i++) iterate(msg);
  console.timeEnd('iterate');
}

function iterate(msg) {
  for (let i=0; i<msg.length; i++);
}
```

```html
<button onclick="splitTest()">Split Test</button>
<button onclick="iterateTest()">Iterate Test</button>
```

Note: I've only tested this on Google Chrome (Mac OS).

The point is, no matter what you do inside that for loop, you won't beat the performance of `split`. I imagine `reduce` may also have the same effect.